# QWT installation error - nmake fails

Tags: c++, qt, charts, installation, qwt

For displaying charts in my C++ project, I want to use *QWT* with *Qt*. I have downloaded *QWT* of the last version from *sourceforge*, and I have downloaded Qt libraries 4.8.1 for MSVC2008 (my compiler) from the official web page. Now I want to install *QWT*, but I cannot complete the installation. The threads I had found on SO did not resolve my problem.

This is the installation as explained in the documentation to *QWT*:

```
F.e Qt >= 3.0, MSVC with nmake:
qmake qwt.pro
nmake
cd examples
qmake examples.pro
nmake
```

I launch *qmake* from Qt 4.8.1 Command Prompt, it creates three *Makefile*s. Now I am supposed to start *nmake*, but *nmake* fails without being able to find any *Qt* header file. I call *nmake* from the Visual Studio command prompt.

```
c:\program files (x86)\qwt\include\qwt_array.h(25) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qmemarray.h': No such file or directory
qwt_plot_curve.cpp
c:\program files (x86)\qwt\include\qwt_array.h(25) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qmemarray.h': No such file or directory
qwt_plot_grid.cpp
c:\program files (x86)\qwt\include\qwt_array.h(25) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qmemarray.h': No such file or directory
qwt_plot_item.cpp
c:\program files (x86)\qwt\include\qwt_array.h(25) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qmemarray.h': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
Compiling...
qwt_plot_print.cpp
src\qwt_plot_print.cpp(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qpaintdevicemetrics.h': No such file or directory
```

What do I do wrong? How should I install *QWT* so that it sees my *Qt* include files?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved my problem by downloading the latest release candidate version of *QWT* and following the instructions to this version in **INSTALL** file. But why the old version did not compile - I haven't got any clue!